# Xcode 11 - Swift Compiler Error on UITableViewAutomaticDimension OR UITableView.automaticDimension

Tags: swift, xcode, uitableview, xcode11

I just got a `Swift Compiler Error` after upgrading to Xcode 11. I am using UITableView in my UIViewController. So I am delegating the UITableView to UIView. I am using the automatic height for the tableview cell using `UITableView.automaticDimension` (This work just fine since I was using Xcode 8). And Xcode Error suggestion appear saying `'automaticDimension' has been renamed to 'UITableViewAutomaticDimension'` . So I followed the suggestion and changed my code into `UITableViewAutomaticDimension`. Few seconds after builds, new suggestion appear on current code saying `'UITableViewAutomaticDimension' has been renamed to 'UITableView.automaticDimension'` and so on if I changed vice versa. Is there anyone having the same problem as I do?[image: Xcode Screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

```
// Swift 4.2 onwards
table.rowHeight = UITableView.automaticDimension
table.estimatedRowHeight = UITableView.automaticDimension

// Swift 4.1 and below
table.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
table.estimatedRowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but even though I change my code into `UITableView.automaticDimension` the error suggestion didn't disapear.

Comment: When posting an answer please explain how your answer solves the question rather than just posting a chunk of code.